# Why can't I use |a,b| instead of |(a,b)| in arr.map { |(a, b)| !b.nil? ? a + b : a }?

Tags: ruby

In the code below, arr is meant to be a two-dimensional array, such as `[[1,2],[4,5]]`. It computes the sum of the elements of the sub arrays. A subarray can have only one element, in which case the sum is just that one element.

```
def compute(arr)
  return nil unless arr
  arr.map { |(a, b)| !b.nil? ? a + b : a }
end
```

Why does the code have to be `|(a, b)|` instead of `|a,b|`?
What does `(a,b)` mean in Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are equivalent if `arr` is an array:

```
arr = [[1, 2], [4, 5]]
arr.map { |a, b| [a, b] }   #=> [[1, 2], [4, 5]]
arr.map { |(a, b)| [a, b] } #=> [[1, 2], [4, 5]]
```

This is because the block is called with a single argument at a time: the subarray. Something like:

```
yield [1, 2]
yield [4, 5]
```

This changes if more than one arguments is yielded. [`each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) for example, calls the block with two arguments: the item (i.e. the subarray) and its index. Something like:

```
yield [1, 2], 0
yield [4, 5], 1
```

The difference is obvious:

```
enum = [[1, 2], [4, 5]].each_with_index
enum.map { |a, b| [a, b] }   #=> [[[1, 2], 0], [[4, 5], 1]]
enum.map { |(a, b)| [a, b] } #=> [[1, 2], [4, 5]]
```

Note that omitting parenthesis also allows you to set a default argument value:

```
arr = [[1, 2], [4]]
arr.map { |a, b = 0| a + b } #=> [3, 4]
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use `|a,b|` too, it's nothing different from `|(a,b)|`.

You may also rewrite the code as below, which doesn't have the element number limit for the sub arrays:

```
 arr.map { |a| a.inject{ |sum,x| sum + x } }
```

or even:

```
arr.map { |a| a.inject(:+) }
```

Comment: It is more idiomatic to write `a.inject(:+)`, however (or `a.inject(&:+)` if you're really attached to passing in a proc).

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Yep, add to the answer.